# Why the moment-generating function, rather than the characteristic function?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, generating-functions, moment-generating-functions

I'm wondering why the moment-generating function is worth discussing (say, in basic probability courses, or in textbooks, rather than research), when the characteristic function appears to completely supersede it.

The "technology" involved is approximately the same, and a lot of the properties correspond, but the characteristic function has several huge advantages over the MGF, such as

1. Existence for any probability distribution
2. Lévy's continuity theorem
3. Inversion formula using the Fourier inversion theorem.

The only (pretty trivial) disadvantage that I can see is that the characteristic function requires knowledge of complex numbers.

Does the MGF have some advantage I'm missing?

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this as well. Note that it's more than just adding complex *numbers*, though: you really have to do some complex *analysis* to do the integrals rigorously. Also note that the MGF can be viewed as the Laplace transform. I wonder if that makes it useful for things the CF isn't good for.

Comment: See here for a detailed discussion of the moment generating function: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32706/existence-of-the-moment-generating-function-and-variance

Comment: [Cumulants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant) are usually defined in terms of the MGF and have have some nice properties. For example, the third and higher-order cumulants of a normal distribution are zero, and it is the only distribution with this property. It seems that it is possible to define the cumulants in terms of the characteristic function as well (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant#Alternative_definition_of_the_cumulant_generating_function)), but it is uncommon (at least in statistics).

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the MGF's advantage that you've identified (its avoidance of complex numbers) seems trivial; but then again I was trained in Engineering, where the complex plane is taught sooner.

The thinking seems quite different in Statistics. For example:

- In DeGroot and Schervish's *Probability and Statistics*, are complex numbers ever even mentioned?
- Ditto for Wackerly et al's *Mathematical Statistics with Applications*, another popular textbook.
- In John Rice's *Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis*, after MGFs are described there's a brief mention of the CF. However, this ends with a warning that "using the characteristic function requires some familiarity with the techniques of complex variables".

So, perhaps you've answered your question better than you thought!

Answer (score 1):

While for most uses, the characteristic function is the strictly superior tool, there are some instances where the moment generating function is more useful. One example is in Large Deviation Theory.

Essentially, Large Deviation Theory (LDT) is about results like the Central Limit Theorem, except about "larger deviations" than the CLT is about. Specifically, if $S_{n}$ is a sum of i.i.d random variables with mean $\mu$, the CLT asks about the probability of $P(|n^{-1} S_{n} - \mu| > z/n^{1/2})$, whereas LDT asks about $n^{-1} \log P(|S_{n}/n - \mu| > z)$. That is, it is more about the tail probabilities than the probability near the mean.

Generally, the results of LDT are of the form
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{-1} \log P(|S_{n}/n - \mu| > z) =-I(z)$$
for some rate function $I(z)$. Where the MGF shows up is in deriving $I(z)$. For instance, in [Cramer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_theorem_(large_deviations)), the rate function is the Legendre transform of the log MGF. Without context, this may seem arbitrary, but essentially the idea is that the MGF allows a certain way of approximating the distribution (using all the moments at once), and the Legendre transform just comes out of the fact that you take the supremum of many bounds on the log probability. As far as I understand, this is a very different way of using the MGF than the way we usually use the characteristic function, and trying to use the characteristic function instead here would not really work (if only because the fact that it is complex would get in the way).

For sake of honesty, I should admit I don't really know much of LDT and the above may be inaccurate; I happened to be wondering about this question myself and figured I'd share what little I've found so far.

Answer (score 0):

The MGF does not always exist, so for example, you cannot use MGF to prove the central limit theorem without imposing a very strong assumption.  Note MGF's existence implies the existence of all moments (but this is not sufficient), while the CLT requires only second moment to exist.

Comment: This seems to be a comment rather than an answer, I think.